# Can we reduce the tab size in <w:tab> in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, cpu-word

I want the size of tab in `<w:tab>` to be reduced in below code:

```
<xsl:template match = "para" mode="paragraph">
     <w:p>
       <w:r>
       <w:rPr><w:tab/></w:rPr>
       <w:t><xsl:value-of="."></w:t>
       </w:r>
     </w:p>
</xsl:template>
```

The tags starting with `<w>` are word compatible tags.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your question is about, as your sample has an empty `<w:tab/>` element. In what way do you expect "to reduce the tab size" with that empty element? Is that question about using XSLT or about the semantics of the Word XML vocabulary?

Comment: Just a comment Tabs have no "size". They are "stop" positions. So the question is worded incorrectly. I would assume you mean how can someone set the tab stop positions.

Comment: See http://officeopenxml.com/WPtab.php which shows you how to set stops in word processing markup

Comment: Thanks a lot @KevinBrown...Still a newbie into the field(sorry).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.